# Use the send-proxy and heartbeat detection functions of haproxy

Tags: haproxy

If my haprox[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDvMS.png)y configuration file contains the configurations of "send-proxy" and "check" for heartbeat detection, my heartbeat packet will send the proxy first and then disconnect the tcp connection. However, once the proxy packet is sent, there will be a read event on the back-end, and then tcp disconnection will occur. I want the heartbeat packet to be without proxy, how to configure it?

I expect normal service packets to carry the proxy, but not heartbeat packets